# Switching data source during a single transaction using multi tenant implementation

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I've been struggling for a few days to get this working, but it seems that I cannot find a solution to it. That's why I'd like to ask it here.

**Short version**

I have a multi tenant implementation which works with Spring boot, Spring Data JPA and Hibernate. This works like a charm. But now I'd like to implement a functionality where I switch the database (data source) during a single transaction. For example I use similar code in my service class

```
@Autowired
private CustomRepository customRepository;

@Autorwired
private CustomTenantIdentifierResolver customResolver;

@Transactional
public Custom getCustom(String name) {

  // Set the datasource to "one";
  this.customResolver.setIdentifier("one");
  Custom result = this.customRepository.findOneByName(name);

  //If the result is null, switch datasource to default and try again
  this.customResolver.setIdentifier("default");
  result = this.customRepository.findOneByName(name);

  return result;
}
```

The problem is, my data source does not switch. It uses the same source for the second request. I guess I'm doing something terribly wrong here.

*What is the correct way to switch the data source during a single transaction?*

**EDIT (07-06-2016)**
Since I noticed that switching the data source for a single transaction is not going to work, I'll add a followup.

*Would it be possible to switch the data source in between two transactions for a single user request? If so, what would be the correct way to do this?*

**Long Version**

Before moving on, I'd like to mention that my multi tenant implementation is based on the [tutorial provided on this blog](http://anakiou.blogspot.nl/2015/08/multi-tenant-application-with-spring.html).

Now, my goal is to use the default data source as a fallback when the dynamic one (chosen by a custom identifier) fails to find a result. All this needs to be done in a single user request. It doesn't make a difference in the solution uses a single or multiple transactional annotated methods.

Until now I tried a couple things, one of them is described above, another includes the use of multiple transaction managers. That implementation uses a configuration file to create two transaction manager beans which each a different data source.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TransactionConfig {

  @Autowired
  private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

  @Autowired
  private DataSourceProvider dataSourceProvider;

  @Bean(name = "defaultTransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager defaultTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSourceProvider.getDefaultDataSource());
    jpaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jpaTransactionManager;
  }

  @Bean(name = "dynamicTransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager dynamicTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    jpaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jpaTransactionManager;
  }

}
```

Next I split the service method into two separate ones and added the `@Transactional` annotation including the right bean name

```
@Transactional("dynamicTransactionManager")
public Custom getDynamicCustom(String name) {
  ...stuff...
}

@Transactional("defaultTransactionManager")
public Custom getDefaultCustom(String name) {
  ...stuff...
}
```

But it didn't make any difference, the first data source was still used for the second method call (which should use the default transaction manager).

I hope someone can help me find a solution to this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this?

Comment: No sorry. Once Spring ask for a connection from the datasource it keeps using that same connection for the entire transaction/session. There is however a possible solution that involves using multiple EntityManagers, though I haven't tested it and I'm not sure if that allows you to switch EntityManagers dynamically. A quick google let me to this: http://fabiomaffioletti.me/blog/2014/04/15/distributed-transactions-multiple-databases-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-atomikos/

Comment: how about doing the second transaction in a new thread? since transaction associated with thread

Answer (score 2):

Spring provides a variation of DataSource, called **AbstractRoutingDatasource**. It can be used in place of standard DataSource implementations and enables a mechanism to determine which concrete DataSource to use for each operation at runtime. All you need to do is to extend it and to provide an implementation of an abstract determineCurrentLookupKey method.

Keep in mind that **determineCurrentLookupKey** method will be called whenever **TransactionsManager** requests a connection. So, if you want to switch DataSource, you just need to open new transaction.

You can find example here
http://fedulov.website/2015/10/14/dynamic-datasource-routing-with-spring/

Comment: Hello, link-only answers are not best suited on StackOverflow. Please add more details to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just move a transaction over to another datasource. While there is a concept of distributed (or XA) transactions, it consists of separate transactions (in separate data sources) that are treated as if they were part of a single (distributed) transaction.

Comment: I kinda expected that trying to switch the data source during a transaction will break things. But do you know if it it's possible to switch the data source when I use two separate transactions, all in a single user request?

Comment: It doesn't sound completely unfeasible, but I'm not familiar enough with the implementation to be able to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is possible, but i think you should try to avoid switching source during a transaction, for the following reason:

If an error occurs during the second request you will want to roll back the entire transaction, which means switching back to the old source. In order to be able to do that you will need to hold an open connection to that old source: When the transaction is complete you will need to confirm the transaction to that old source.

I would recommend to rethink if you really want this, beside the point if it is possible at all.

Comment: Makes sense. But would it be possible to switch the data source using two separate transactions in a single user request?

Comment: In theory yes, my knowledge of the spring framework is non-existent. It could be it is (partially) limited to a single transaction per request. Which makes sense, if a request fails on the 2nd transaction how will you notify the client the first part succeeded, and the 2nd part did not. Would it not be better for the client to do 2 separate requests, each with its own responsibility. What i mean to say is: Do a step back and have a look at the functionality, and wonder how you got into this situation in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here - MultitenantDataSource works like a charm but if you want to switch tenants within the same request you keep getting the result from the first time the DataSource is resolved.

The determineCurrentLookupKey() method in the subclassed AbstractRoutingDataSource seems to get called only once per session/request.

I tried getting the Repository Bean multiple times (after changing the LookupKey) via the ApplicationContext but it did not help.

My workaround in a REST Application:
I used a RestTemplate to make calls to my own service - the DataSource is then resolved correctly each time.